# date-from-num analogous in python3

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, datetime

I have following code in NodeJS

```
> var dateFromNum = require('date-from-num');
> dateFromNum(1524231846)
2018-04-20T13:44:06.000Z
```

As you can notice 1524231846 returns 2018-04-20T13:44:06.000Z

I am porting the functionality to Python as below

```
from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1524231846)
>>> dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%S')
'20/04/2018 14:06'
```

I am noticing a difference in minutes between Node and Python even after factoring daylight savings. How can I get same time stamp value in Python as I get in NodeJS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want UTC time, then you need to use `utcfromtimestamp()`. Also, you forgot `%M` for minute:

```
In [187]: dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1524231846)

In [189]: dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[189]: '20/04/2018 13:44:06'
```